# Smoothing spline De Boor's approach

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is it possible to find smoothing spline based on De Boor's approach in Python? For data approximation.

Earlier I used Smoothing spline in matlab, I need exactly same algorithm in python.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html). The example below is directly taken from the documentation:

[image]

In this example, the cubic spline is used to interpolate a sampled sinusoid. One can see that the spline continuity property holds for the first and second derivatives and violates only for the third derivative. There is also another example available; not sure what exactly you need.

This is the code needed to produce the figure:

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.sin(x)
cs = CubicSpline(x, y)
xs = np.arange(-0.5, 9.6, 0.1)
plt.figure(figsize=(6.5, 4))
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(xs, np.sin(xs), label='true')
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs), label="S")
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs, 1), label="S'")
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs, 2), label="S''")
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs, 3), label="S'''")
plt.xlim(-0.5, 9.5)
plt.legend(loc='lower left', ncol=2)
plt.show()
```

You can also check [scipy.interpolate.splrep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html#scipy.interpolate.splrep) and [scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline). Furthermore, there is a [github repository](https://github.com/johntfoster/bspline) which might be of help. You can compare these methods to the Matlab function you use and select the appropriate one.